# Singularities in Schwarzchild space-time

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, singularities

Can anyone explain when a co-ordinate and geometric singularity arise in [Schwarzschild space-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) with the element

$$ ds^{2}~=~(1-\frac{2GM}{r})(dt)^{2}-(1-\frac{2GM}{r})^{-1}(dr)^{2}-r^{2}(d\theta)^{2}-(r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta)(d\theta)^{2}$$

Comment: First of all: where are the singularities? You should be able to do that already. Then we can work out whether they are coordinate vs. geometric.

Comment: Is the singulatiry when the coeficient goes to $\infty$ so at r=0 and at infinity?

Comment: If you set $M=0$ you get a flat spacetime metric. That shows that there is no singularity at $r=\infty$, even though $g_{\theta\theta}=\infty$ there. Also, you're missing the place where $g_{rr}$ blows up.

Comment: Hi user21119: did you check the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Singularities_and_black_holes) page?

Comment: yeah thx, so would it be r=0 geometric and then r=2GM co-oridante